# Adding delay on OnAppearing Function

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to add a delay before checking the internet connectivity of my device. I have a function OnAppearing(). When the page has appeared only after X number of seconds will my app checks the device's internet connectivity.

I have 2 questions:
1. How can I add a delay?
2. If I add a delay will my page appear first before the delay starts or my page will appear only after the delay?

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    //Add delay before executing the code below
    if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected){
     //Some code here
    }

}
```

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use a fire and forget task and your page will continue to load/display.

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
        {
            //Some code here

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                 // If you need to update an UI element
            });

        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: Will my page appear first before invoking the function or the page will only appear when the delay has been done?

Comment: It wont work and when I try to navigate to my other page nothing is being displayed

Comment: It is running in a different thread so both are running at the same time, assuming a long enough delay, the page will appear first.

Comment: My navigation. when I navigate to my page all of my page have a delay now

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto ? Are you saying you added a delay to each OnAppearing?

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto you did NOT add an `await` to that Task.Run did you?